How to fix a Transfer Case Actuator that no longer engages
Has anyone ever seen this with their Prado? I've got a 2010 Toyota Landcruiser Prado GX Auto constant 4x4 KDJ150 - KD-FTV. Came back from some 4wding in Jan/Feb after going in between 4Hi and Lo with centre diff lock engaging once or twice as you do and, since then, I've been unable to engage the centre diff lock since coming back and I'm not sure why... a light keeps flashing (pic) and I took a look at the transfer case actuator when I noticed that the centre diff lock wasn’t engaging and this happened:

I took off the cover and removed the 2 main gears to take a look into the transfer case actuator.
I noticed that one of the shafts (which I think is the centre diff lock shaft) could not reach full travel. It got to about 75% of its travel and then couldn’t move further (maybe 15 mm from 100% travel). Refer to the picture attached to see what I’m talking about.
I ended up reassembling the actuator and tried to re-time the gears myself.
When I started the car afterwards there were still the same issues with the centre diff lock not engaging, though I retimed the gears successfully as my cruise control still works. Regardless, the problem (I think) might be related to getting that shaft to go full travel,,? Took it to Toyota after reassembling it 100 times and they wanted a looooot of money to replace the transfer case oil and actuator. Any advice?

Update 1
I knowingly paid a premium to go to Toyota thinking they'd have the solution. The bloke at the desk was great but the job that was done made everything WORSE. Apart from not fixing the problem, they also did not retime the actuator gears after they pulled them apart which led to my cruise control not working (which they admitted in writing once I questioned them via email) and a leaking transfer case! They made the problem worse not better! To top it off they said to fix it all would cost $4-6k and they weren't even sure if their fix would work!!!!
Update 2
I fiddled with it again, taking it apart driving forward and back etc. The light now doesn't flash but stays constant. Pressing the button does not do anything. Right now the centre diff lock is off and pressing the button makes it try to actuate (the light flashes) but that's it, nothing else.
Unbelievable. Any advice? Guess for now I'll just try and avoid getting myself in spots where I need the centre diff lock, but I'm also mindful of the leaking transfer case since Toyota screwed with it...

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'll guarantee you the "$4-6k" quote is to replace the transfer case.

I believe they have to go through the TCase to get to the actuator. But yeah, I'm sure they'd rather just replace the whole thing and rip me off.
